# Python -m unittest with arguments for test generation

Tags: python, unit-testing, arguments, teamcity

I have a CI test server set up where we call `python -m teamcity.unittestpy file.py`. This file.py then loads a JSON file and generates a large number of tests that are completely customizable from that JSON file. This systems works exactly as expected and has been tested over the last 2 weeks.

Now we've decided to change our CI process to no longer make assumptions on which packages (built software) we want to test and thus the test generation should now be adaptable to an extend where I would like to call `python -m teamcity.unittestpy file.py -package packagename` to specify which package is built and which tests are allowed to be generated.

I know that it's common to not use `-m unittest discover` and then `argparse` proves to be a easy to use module to implement this behavior. However, I'm stuck with the `-m teamcity.unittestpy` call of our test suite.

Here is my current status:

```
#general imports stuff

#new argparse imports
import sys
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-package') #package argument. -p foo would generate the 'foo' tests defined in 'foo' folder


class CriticalSessionTests(unittest.TestCase):
    pass

def test_generator():
    def test(self):
        #testdefinition
        self.assertTrue(True)
    return test

def init(options, args):
    PACKAGE = options.p #can be None which would mean NO TESTS                     
    if PACKAGE is not None:
        cwdpath = os.getcwd() 
        path = cwdpath + '\\' + PACKAGE

        #load json file
        #iterate over files in package folder and generate additional tests  

        #generate tests like:
        test_name = "test_TC_{}_{}".format(filename, idx)
        test = test_generator()
        setattr(CriticalSessionTests, test_name, test) 

options, args = parser.parse_known_args() 
init(options, args)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if is_running_under_teamcity():
        runner = TeamcityTestRunner()
    else:
        runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()
    unittest.main(testRunner=runner, argv=sys.argv[:1] + args)
```

Now, please keep in mind that I have the actual test generation working fine. My actual issue is that I cannot pass arguments to this system due to the limitations of a `-m teamcity.unittestpy` call and need to work around it.

I would greatly appreciate pointers to code snippets on how I could construct a wrapper that gets called so that I have the possibility to define arguments. Or any other pointers are very welcome.

EDIT:
In case people are wondering about the errors:

```
python -m unittest tests.py -package a
usage: python.exe -m unittest [-h] [-v] [-q] [--locals] [-f] [-c] [-b]
                              [-k TESTNAMEPATTERNS]
                              [tests [tests ...]]
python.exe -m unittest: error: unrecognized arguments: -package a
```

and if I define it as `package` in the Python file (note there are no '-') then following error occurs:

```
python -m unittest tests.py package a
ERROR: package (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
ImportError: Failed to import test module: p
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C_path\unittest\loader.py", line 154, in loadTestsFromName
    module = __import__(module_name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package '
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this is by no way the desired solution, I can access environment variables and read from these within the test generation to properly handle states. Build agents within TeamCity can define these and this works for my use cases.